# How to use a group by in two sub queries and sum the count of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two different tables without any relation, but I need to sum the count of rows of both, and group by using dates. I need in this way, because I need to plot a chart at Metabase.

I need this to sum how many video ads my users are watching each day and unfortunately it is divided.

I tried this SQL and almost worked:

```
select *, total_video_prize + total_video_stock
from (select last_video_watched, count(*) as total_video_prize from video_ads_user_historic group by DAY(last_video_watched)) as video_prize,
(select date_when_transacted, count(*) as total_video_stock from stock_historic where has_seen_video_ad = true group by DAY(date_when_transacted)) as video_stock
```

The problem was that the dates were not merged. I need the last_video_watched be the same of date_when_transacted, grouped by day. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Try adding INNER JOIN on your result sets by date.  If you have large sets of data I would put results into a temp table for each group and then join those 2 together

Comment: A great tip is NEVER use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an UNION for get the day and then join  with the subquery  for count

```
select  t1.my_day , t2.total_video_prize , t3.total_video_stock
from (
    select DAY(date_when_transacted) as my_day
    from  stock_historic 
    union 
    select DAY(last_video_watched)
    from video_ads_user_historic 
) t1 
left join  (

    select DAY(last_video_watched) my_day, count(*) as total_video_prize 
    from video_ads_user_historic 
    group by DAY(last_video_watched)

) t2 on t2.myday = t1.my_day

left join  (
    selectDAY(date_when_transacted) my_day, count(*) as total_video_stock 
    from stock_historic 
    where has_seen_video_ad = true 
    group by DAY(date_when_transacted)

) t3 on t3.my_day = t1.my_day
```

Comment: Thank you! I just changed DAY to DATE... it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Renan Geraldo: Just to let you know, this query would usually be written with a full outer join and be much simpler then. MySQL, however, still doesn't support full outer joins, so we must clumsily workaround this. scaisEdge has used the typical approach here to first collect all keys (dates in this case) and then outer join the data sets to the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Each record represents a movie watched, no matter which of the two tables. So glue the tables's rows together with `UNION ALL` and count:

```
select dt, count(*)
from
(
  select last_video_watched as dt from video_ads_user_historic
  union all
  select date_when_transacted as dt from stock_historic where has_seen_video_ad = true
) unioned
group by dt
order by dt;
```

If your date columns contain a time part, then use `DATE(column)` instead of the mere column.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is simply `union all` and `group by`:

```
select date(dt), sum(is_video_prize) as total_video_prize,
       sum(is_video_stock) as total_video_stock
from ((select last_video_watched as dt, 1 as is_video_prize, 0 as is_video_stock
       from video_ads_user_historic
      ) union all
      (select date_when_transacted as dt, 0, 1
       from stock_historic
       where has_seen_video_ad = true
      )
     ) vp
group by date(dt)
order by date(dt);
```

No joins are necessary.